# Python Class __init__ Not Working

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy

This is some really simple code I am using with sqlalchemy and I am missing something basic here about how classes work.

```
class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = "games"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
             setattr(self, k, v)
        print 'hi'
        self.away_dictionary =  {'name': self.a_name}

    @hybrid_property
    def stuff(self):
        return self.away_dictionary
```

The following query works:

```
session.query(Game).first().a_name
```

but the following query returns an error:

```
session.query(Game).first().stuff
'Game' object has no attribute 'away_dictionary'
```

I also have an even more basic problem, when I query the Game class it doesn't print out 'hi'.  So could someone please explain why 'hi' isn't printed out everytime I use a Game instance? And the second question is how can I build and access the away_dictionary I want to have for each instance of this class?

Comment: any reason you have leftout `*args` in the signature of `__init__` ?

Comment: @karthikr: because SQLAlchemy doesn't use positional arguments to create instances of model objects?

Comment: You need to make sure that whatever is returned by `session.query(Game).first()` is what you think it is; inspect the result of `dir()` on it; look for it's `__module__` and `__file__` attributes, etc.

Comment: Sanity check: That *is* the right `Game` class, right? You're not accidentally redefining Game later or anything? And you copy-pasted it right out of your source, so there's no typo in `__init__` or `stuff`?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in my post.  the error it throws is "Game object has no attribute 'away_dictionary'" - [[previously i wrote the error it throws was "Game object has no attribute 'stuff'"]]

Comment: lol in my case I had an additional _ after init -____-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the comments.  is it just me or is sqlalchemy kind of confusing?

anyway, as people have pointed out above the `__init__` method apparently is not called when you do a query.

> The SQLAlchemy ORM does not call `__init__` when recreating objects from
>   database rows. The ORM’s process is somewhat akin to the Python
>   standard library’s pickle module, invoking the low level `__new__`
>   method and then quietly restoring attributes directly on the instance
>   rather than calling `__init__`.

the solution to this is to add the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import reconstructor
@reconstructor
awesome_true_init(self):
    self.away_dictionary = {'hi': 'i work!!'}
```

this function will act like a real `__init__` and get called whenever you create the object!!

Comment: i got this solution from here btw, http://www.appneta.com/2012/06/18/advanced-sqlalchemy-performance-concerns/

Comment: Nice find.  Disappointingly, this `awesome_true_init` can't be called `__init__`. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating a Game instance in your queries above, you only pass the Game class object. Hence the **init**() constructor is never called.
If you need a Game instance for query, you need this: `session.query(Game()).first().stuff`.

Comment: You misunderstand how SQLAlchemy works; the `session.query()` call takes the type as a basis for SQL queries, and the result of the query is used to return an instance of that type. The OP has a reasonable expectation that SQLAlchemy will create that instance and thus invoke the `__init__`. Passing in an instance to `query()` instead is the *wrong* thing to do!

Comment: I don't misunderstand - I just don't don't know, that's why I wrote **If** you need a Game instance for query.... He was asking why his constructor wasn't called and it wasn't called, because he passed a class object and no instance.

Comment: No, that is not why. SQLAlchemy creates the instances here, and that appears to not happen. And that is indeed puzzling. You misunderstand how the SQLAlchemy API works.

Comment: Correct he needed `Game()` instead of `Game` or `__init__` will not be executed

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha. I was just about to point out that it's bizarre that `stuff` isn't getting found, and I would expect `away_dictionary` not to be found instead... and you edited your post and changed the error message that you're quoting. It is indeed `away_dictionary` that isn't getting found, because it's normally created in your class's `__init__()` method and `__init__()` isn't getting called.

Normally, `__init__()` would be called when you create an instance, but when you use the class in SQLAlchemy's queries, it's skipping the `__init__()` method. I suspect this is something to do with how SQLAlchemy's `declarative_mapper` works, but I'm rusty enough on SQLAlchemy that I don't know off the top of my head how to fix it. If I find out, I'll edit this answer later and tell you.

But for now, you should probably not rely on your `__init__()` method getting called in your SQLAlchemy model objects (that is, anything derived from `Base`). See if you can structure your code in some other way.

Answer (score -2):

The reason  `session.query(Game).first().a_name`works, but `session.query(Game).first().stuff` doesn't is a simple syntactic issue. a_name is a variable, an attribute of the class Game, so you refer to it just by typing a_name. stuff, on the other hand, is a method of that class, so you need a pair of parentheses after it, even if, as in this case, there isn't anything inside them. So try using `session.query(Game).first().stuff()`.

"hi" isn't being printed because **init** is only called when you create an object using that constructor, which query isn't doing.

Comment: Even if `stuff` is a method, accessing it should *not* throw an attribute error.